# Google Spreadsheets - Unable to fetch the domain linkedin.com through importhtml and importxml

Tags: google-sheets

I'm unable to access the linkedin.com domain through the "importhtml" and "importxml" functions in Google Spreadsheets. However, the domain twitter.com works absolutely fine.

Any idea what might be the issue?

Ref:
Code that I'm using - =IMPORTHTML("https://linkedin.com/company/tracxn","table",1)

Error Message that I'm getting - Error: Could not fetch url https://linkedin.com/company/tracxn

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/56347/prohibited-software-and-extensions?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

> **Prohibited Software and Extensions**
>
> LinkedIn is committed to keeping its members' data safe and its website free from fraud and abuse. In order to protect our members' data and our website, we don't permit the use of any third party software, including "crawlers", bots, browser plug-ins, or browser extensions (also called "add-ons"), that scrapes, modifies the appearance of, or automates activity on LinkedIn's website. Such tools violate the User Agreement, including, but not limited to, many of the "Don'ts" listed in Section 8.2:
>
> - Develop, support or use software, devices, scripts, robots, or any other means or processes (including crawlers, browser plugins and add-ons, or any other technology) to scrape the Services or otherwise copy profiles and other data from the Services;
> - Use bots or other automated methods to access the Services, add or download contacts, send or redirect messages;
> - Overlay or otherwise modify the Services or their appearance (such as by inserting elements into the Services or removing, covering, or obscuring an advertisement included on the Services);
> - Copy, use, disclose or distribute any information obtained from the Services, whether directly or through third parties (such as search engines), without the consent of LinkedIn;
> - Override any security feature or bypass or circumvent any access controls or use limits of the Service (such as caps on keyword searches or profile views);
> - Deep-link to our Services for any purpose other than to promote your profile or a Group on our Services, without LinkedIn’s consent.
>
> Any member who uses tools for such purposes is in violation of the User Agreement. This means they risk having their accounts being restricted or shut down. They also risk the possibility that these tools may become non-operational without notice. In order to keep our members' data safe, we're constantly working to improve our technical measures and defenses against the operation of scraping, automation, and other tools that abuse LinkedIn's platform.
>
> **[https://www.linkedin.com/help/](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/56347/prohibited-software-and-extensions?lang=en)**

### **in other words - it's not possible to scrape LinkedIn**